# Apache Jena does not add hasPart relationship

Tags: java, transactions, jena

I'm wokring on a large complex piece of software reading data from a system and storing portions of it in a Apache Jena `Model`/`DataSet`. Everything works fine, except for one small thing: when attempting to add a 'hasPart' relationship between two entities in the model it never gets applied.

I.e. when I debug the code I can see that log4j reports an error that seemingly indicates the transcation not being active.

So, to my question: what might cause this situation, an opened transaction not being active? 
It seems quite confusing as the line prior to adding the property 'hasPart' is starting the transaction (`begin(ReadWrite.WRITE)` on the `DataSet`)). No exception is thrown, just the log4j logged error message on the console.

Unfortuanely, currently I cannot produce a minimal piece of code that demonstrates the problem in a timely manner. So my question is more of the nature if some kind soul has a pointer or a theorectical explanation - it will be most useful. Any pointer or explanation will be greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is little the SO community can help with if you don't provide even a log trace or a code snippet (doesn't have to be directly executable, but an MWE helps).

First, you should use [DCMI `hasPart` term](http://dublincore.org/documents/dcmi-terms/#terms-hasPart) for representing `hasPart` relationship.

I recommend that you [check all Model statements](https://jena.apache.org/tutorials/rdf_api.html#ch-Statements) before you save it. After that [make sure you are in a Transaction](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/org/apache/jena/query/Dataset.html#isInTransaction--).

If this helps you, please update the question properly so that this can become an answer to a *real question*, not just a vague description of the problem.

Comment: The log output on the console looks like: [ERROR] Not active: 11514 - and I think it originates from a class named BlockMgrJournal, method: checkActive.

Comment: https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-tdb/src/main/java/org/apache/jena/tdb/transaction/BlockMgrJournal.java#L300 seems to be the source of the message. Are you trying to open write transactions on the data files of a running Fuseki? If so, you should not be doing it. If you still want to do it, make sure your Java app and Fuseki are run in the same process: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/faqs.html#multi-jvm

Answer (score 1):

It proved that extracting the resource from the `Dataset` and using that reference instead (the code was holding a reference to the instance created in the first place) adding the property (hasPart) proved to work as expected. No error reported by the logging framework, and the hasPart-property is in place.

The resources affected resides in the default graph of the `Dataset`.

*Observation*: using `getResource(uri)` does return the resource, but it seems to be a copy (?) as the instance id:s differ.

Thanks berezovskiy for helping out on the details of this.